# Problems with MySQL Complex Insert (Mutli Row Insert with Sub Select)

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I'm having an issue with the following query. With the query I'm attempting to insert a row into the notification table for each user who matches the sub select for the recipient id field.

The query I have is as follows, but is not working:

```
INSERT INTO
notification (type,
      target_id,
      sender_id,
      recipient_id,
      data,
      timestamp,
      is_unread)
      ('post',
       '$id',
       '$senderId',
       (SELECT user_id FROM group_member WHERE group_id = '$id'),
       '1',
       '$timestamp',
       '1')
```

I also tried using VALUES prefixed to the information I am attempting to insert, but I read somewhere that for multi row inserts you're supposed to exclude it and just use the values in parenthesis as I have above?

Comment: If you want to embed variables in your strings, you should wrap them in double quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your variables are properly escaped, you can do

```
INSERT INTO
  notification (type,target_id,sender_id,recipient_id,
  data,`timestamp`,is_unread)
  SELECT 'post', '$id','$senderId',user_id, '1','$timestamp', '1'
  FROM group_member WHERE group_id = '$id'
```